# panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [2:1]

Tags: string, go

I am working on an academic problem and Go panics.
The code will find the middle charcter of a string.

```
func findMiddle(s string) string {
    len := len(s)
    half := len / 2

    if len == 0 {
        panic("zero")
    }

    if len%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Println("#53:" + s)
        str := s[half-1:1] + s[half:1]
        fmt.Println("Even: " + str)
        return str
    } else {
        fmt.Println("#58: " + s)
        str := s[half:1]
        fmt.Println("Odd: " + str)
        return str
    }
}
```

My debug output looks like:

```
#58: 1
Odd: 1
#58: 2
Odd: 2
#58: 5
Odd: 5
#53:13
Even: 1
#53:89
Even: 8
#58: 233
Odd: 
#53:1597
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [2:1]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.findMiddle(0xc00001a200, 0x4, 0xc00001a200, 0x4)
        /home/peter/work/src/misc2/prime-recursion-strings/main.go:68 +0x403
main.iterate(0x4f8bc0, 0xc00009c008)
        /home/peter/work/src/misc2/prime-recursion-strings/main.go:30 +0x92
main.main()
        /home/peter/work/src/misc2/prime-recursion-strings/main.go:17 +0xa3
exit status 2
```

As you can see the code runs multiple iterations before it panics.

Any clue to what is happening? 
Test the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/_K1DivJST3F

Comment: Please show the entire panic message. It tells you exactly which line of your code caused the problem.

Comment: The line number won't do much good unless we also know which line that is in the code you provided.  It would be best to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can try it for ourselves.

Comment: Entire panic message addded above.
Code added on Go playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[2:1]` is an invalid slice index.  The proper format is `[low:high]`, so the second number must always be larger than (or equal to) the first. This is why you get a panic.

The solution is to replace:

```golang
        str := s[half-1:1] + s[half:1]
```

with:

```golang
        str := s[half-1:half] + s[half:half+1]
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0TsxhUuyhhQ), which can be further simplified to:

```golang
        str := s[half-1:half+1]
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VBXZxzIixQY)